# AngularJS + Bootstrap-UI: tooltip not hidden when button is disabled

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm creating a web app using AngularJS + Twitter Bootstrap and Bootstrap-UI. When I place a tooltip on a button, it shows as expected; but if the button gets *disabled* (by the underlying controller) after being clicked, and the tooltip was being shown, the tooltip is not hidden and stays there forever. Here's a repro:

Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/numlaAuLOxh3a03Z7O85/preview

Just hover the button to make the tooltip appear, and then click it. The button is disabled, and the tooltip stays there. How can I avoid this behavior and have my tips correctly hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that using simply replacing buttons with anchor tags worked perfectly for me.

```
<a role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
    ng-click="someAction()" tooltip="Tooltip" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, even if I did not yet check with the latest Angular+Bootstrap versions.

Comment: You saved My day :) thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: `disabled=""`, generated by `ng-disabled=""` is not supported by `<a>` tags

Answer (score 2):

Searching through GitHub issues I found the [suggestion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1025) (seems to be related to the [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2059) opened by you?) to use wrapping element that has a tooltip around the element: http://jsfiddle.net/RWZmu/

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" tooltip="My Tooltip">
  <button class="navbar-btn btn-danger" ng-click="test()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" tooltip="Here's the tip">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I posted this to GitHub: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2059 Yet there seems to be no solution at this time, other than wrapping the potentially disabled element and moving the tooltip outside. This anyway results in a suboptimal grow of HTML markup just for the purpose of correctly handle the tip...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following logic here

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-app="someApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" 
 class="likes" tooltip="show favorites" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
 ng-click="doSomething()">{{likes}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('someApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
'mouseenter': 'mouseleave',
'click': 'click',
'focus': 'blur',
'hideonclick': 'click'
});
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.likes = 999;
$scope.doSomething = function(){
    //hide the tooltip
    $scope.tt_isOpen = false;
};
```

})

Souce

[Hide angular-ui tooltip on custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730461/hide-angular-ui-tooltip-on-custom-event)

http://jsfiddle.net/3ywMd/10/

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add the app.config code plus the tt_isOpen instruction (even if it sounds a bit tricky, and forces my controller to take care of visualization issues); yet it does not seem to work. Updated plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/numlaAuLOxh3a03Z7O85/preview. Did I miss something?