# Angular UI tooltip in ng-repeat not closing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please see the plunker below: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/RPpjULZsSDnTFPKiafl2

Basically, the angular-ui tooltip remains when moving up / down to a position where ng-disabled is true.  Any thoughts on how to fix the issue would be much appreciated!

I'm using Chrome, but the issue appears more serious in Firefox where even with ng-disabled removed the tooltips still remain on mouseleave.

Comment: Why are you separating the element attributes using a comma? That's not valid html.  In any case [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16653079/238427) especially the edit based on @cotten comments.  That seems to be the same issue that you have

Comment: Thanks @JoseM!  I did see that answer before posting but couldn't get it to solve my problem.  I actually also have an issue where the tooltip actually moves as well when you move an item in a repeat but I wasn't able to replicate that in a plunker so is probably a scope issue.  The commas are just cause I'm clearly spending too much time writing in Jade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$tooltipProvider` and alter the trigger map to take `click` as an additional hide trigger for the `mouseenter` show trigger:

```
myApp.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
  $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
    'mouseenter': 'mouseleave click'
  });
}]);
```

v0.9.0 of AngularUI suffered from [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1339) which caused errors (although still worked) on delete buttons (for instance) which had a tooltip. This has been subsequently fixed in v0.10.0.

[Here's a demo of it in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/uA58gpZld0OSd7RUSUXg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I assume ng-disabled also disables any events from triggering on the buttons. Then, when you move a row down to the last row (or up to the first), the event handlers are disabled before the `mouseout` event is handled. It works if you trigger the `mouseout` event "manually" when the click event is handled.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vuax2rEJurGeqoXjFdm8?p=preview)

This may actually be a bug worth pointing out to the angular team.