# Customize AngularJS Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-controller

How do I add custom placements/animations to an AngularJS/Bootstrap tooltip?  I can do:

```
myApp.controller('TooltipCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.htmlTooltip = 'Here is a tooltip!';
});
```

And it works perfectly, but if I add:

```
$scope.setTriggers({
  placement: 'right'
});
```

inside the controller, I get an **"undefined is not a function"** error.  What am I syntactically doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also tried doing this:

```
myApp.controller('TooltipCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.placement = 'right';
  $scope.htmlTooltip = 'Here is a tooltip!';
});
```

but it seems to have no effect on the placement on the tooltip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to configure of the "$tooltipProvider".

$tooltipProvider is a provider hence configurable only in  the CONFIG Phase of angular.

You will have to try it setting it in the CONFIG Phase of angular.

```
    angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .config(['$tooltipProvider', function ($tooltipProvider) {
        $tooltipProvider.options({
            placement: 'right'
        });
    }])
```

Comment: Syntactically what you just posted is incorrect.. you have an extra bracket and stuff.  Also why are you using `=` instead of `:`?  It says on the Angular BootStrap UI to use the line `placement: 'right'`, I'm just not sure how to incorporate it into the controller.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730461/hide-angular-ui-tooltip-on-custom-event.  Do I have to add something to my routes.js?

Comment: @Hubrid `$tooltipProvider.options` sets the *default* for tooltips. From your question, it sounds like you're looking for "custom *placements*" (emphasis is mine), meaning not the defaults but config for individual tooltips. Is that me just misunderstanding your wording?

Comment: I see that you've changed it, but you have in such a way that sets the *defaults* for tooltips. What I'm asking the OP is whether this is truly what they want, because their original question is ambiguous but seems to indicate that it's not.

Comment: Either way works.  I meant individual tooltips originally, but I think all of my tooltips will have the same right placement, so it doesn't matter practically.  That being said, I'm still interested in how you would set individual defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Angular $tooltipProvider has been changed to $uibTooltipProvider. Try this.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function ($uibTooltipProvider)
{
   $tooltipProvider.options({
   placement: 'right'
  });
}]);
```