# UI-Bootstrap - Popover/Tooltip for mobile display

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap-UI Tooltip/Popover-directive in mobile displays.
If the User clicks a button with a Tooltip, this Popover is shown correctly. But unfortunately this popup will not close if the user clicks somewhere else.

Does everyone had the same problem and found a solution for this?

I use the latest version (0.12.1).

Comment: Could you please provide an example? What is your settings for `tooltip-trigger`?

Comment: This is for example a tooltip I use in my application:                                <span popover="This is a test"
        popover-placement="right"
        popover-popup-delay="1000"
        popover-trigger="mouseenter">test
</span>

Comment: This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXxO17LTC72JcXrRV7EQ?p=preview) works as expected on my mobile device (Android 5.0.1, Chrome)

Comment: but this only works with jquery dependency. Is there a solution only with angular?

Comment: it works for me even without jquery (I have updated the plunker)

Comment: thank you for the replay. Then I think it is a problem with Safari :/ . Even the updated plunker does not work in safari.

Comment: Did you try other `tooltip-trigger` settings?

Comment: yes, for example focus doesn't work. The demands for this project is "mouseenter". So I think I have no other possibility than "mouseenter" even if it doesn't work for safari.

Comment: You could try some workarounds like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23571713/1696578

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick="void(0)"` behavior to some of your background elements which when tapped will get rid of the popovers.

credits: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2123

Answer (score 0):

The default triggerMap for the tooltip looks like so:

```
  var triggerMap = {
    'mouseenter': 'mouseleave',
    'click': 'click',
    'focus': 'blur'
  };
```

The mouseenter show trigger has a dismiss trigger of mouseleave.  You can try creating your own trigger and adding a blur dismiss trigger like so:

```
'mouseenter': 'mouseleave blur'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the most success using CSS to allow iOS to detect the "body" (and any nested element that would bubble down) as a clickable element and therefor trigger a "click" event, like you'd expect on a desktop device.

This media query will target touch devices, and not cause a cursor style change on desktop devices. It solves for both Tooltips and Popovers, including tooltips that use `mouseenter` or `outsideClick`.

```
@media (hover: none), (pointer: coarse) {
    body {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

I wasn't having issues in Android on Chrome, but the above will fix it for Mobile iOS on Safari or Chrome.